# Python cant create loop in mouse replay program

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python script that can read a text file of numbers and set every other number into a list of x coordinates and does the same thing for y. then i am trying to create a loop that can move the mouse using the x and y list. I am fairly new to python and i keep getting supplied sequence must have 2 element errors. I don't know if their is anything that i am doing wrong.
the list of numbers looks like this:

> 1 2 3 4

and my code is this

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
f = open('mouse_log.txt', 'r')
coords = [] 

for line in f:
    inftemp = line.strip()
    coords.append(inftemp)

xlist = []
ylist = []

xlist.append(coords[::2])
ylist.append(coords[1::2])

temp = 0

for x in coords:
    pyautogui.moveTo(xlist[temp],ylist[temp])
    temp = temp + 1
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Kade
>   Hugh\Desktop\python stuff\MousePlayback.py", line 20, in 
>       pyautogui.moveTo(xlist[temp],ylist[temp])   File "C:\Users\Kade Hugh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyautogui__init__.py",
>   line 611, in moveTo
>       x, y = _unpackXY(x, y)   File "C:\Users\Kade Hugh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyautogui__init__.py",
>   line 180, in _unpackXY
>       raise ValueError('The supplied sequence must have exactly 2 elements ({0} were received).'.format(len(x))) ValueError: The
>   supplied sequence must have exactly 2 elements (3 were received).

Comment: Copy and paste the actual (complete) exception here, don't just give us a vague description of it.

Comment: @abarnert just did

Comment: OK, the error message you've given us doesn't match the problem you claim you're having.

Comment: @abarnert I changed it to state my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your example, `coords` is a list of 4 numbers, and `xlist` and `ylist` are lists of 2 numbers.

You loop over the four elements in `coords`, adding 1 to `temp` each time. So, you're looking up `xlist[0], ylist[0]`, then `xlist[1], ylist[1]`, then `xlist[2], ylist[2]`, then `xlist[3], ylist[3]`. But there *is* no `xlist[2]`, `ylist[2]`, `xlist[3]`, or `ylist[3]`, so of course you're going to get an error if you try to access them.

What you want to do is loop 2 times, not 4—or, more generally, loop over the number of elements in `xlist` and `ylist`, not the number of elements in `coords`.

The cleanest way to do this is to just loop over the lists directly, instead of trying to figure out a number to loop over. The only tricky bit is that you have two separate lists, which you want to loop over in lock-step with each other. But that's exactly what [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is for:

```
for x, y in zip(xlist, ylist):
    pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
```